# Sed - Remove all script tags

Tags: linux, sed

I am using the windows rewrite of SED from http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/ssed/ to try and remove all script tags from a file. I am using this command

```
sed "/<script/,/<\/script>/d" "C:/myfolder/test.html"
```

But this is not working for me and is just returning the word 'test'

I know this might be an issue with the windows version of sed but in terms of the command, does it look correct?

Comment: An initial worry: how robust are you expecting this to be? If this is intended to provide security it is not a good idea. Use a proper parser.

Comment: don't do this!  using html parser!  if you know sed's `/../, /.../` address, you should know that, if your script start and end element are in same line, your script will remove all texts after the script tag!

Answer (score 0):

You can test such utilities online for example on [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler).
The following:

```
echo 'abc
<script>
def
</script>
xyz' | sed "/<script/,/<\/script>/d"
```

outputs:

```
abc
xyz
```

so it looks ok.
Maybe you are using a wrong file?
You can also install cygwin on windows and install a good sed with cygwin.